# Nested ng-repeat $index is not working right

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Here i want to make a page numbering that increments everytime the ng-repeat increments but what i get is that the second ng-repeat index is always zero but using the index of the first ng-repeat works fine through $parent.$index how can this be solved?
here is the code sample  :

```
<div ng-repeat="chapter in plan.chapters" class="export-page" >
                      <div  ng-repeat="section in chapter.sections track by section.id" class="export-page" ng-init="sectionindex = $index">

                          <div class="header">
                              <br>
                              <h2 class="headerTitle">
                                <b>{{$root.selectedCompany.name + ' | ' + chapter.subject}}</b>
                              </h2>
                          </div>

                          <div class="content">
                              <h1><b>{{chapter.subject}}</b></h1>
                              <h2 class="chapter" >{{section.subject}}</h2>

                              <br>

                              <p ng-if="section.content_type === 'text'">
                                <div ng-bind-html="section.content.text"></div>
                              </p>

                              <p ng-if="section.content_type === 'table'">
                                <numeric-table model="section.content"
                                              disable-editing="true"
                                              hide-input-controls="true">
                                </numeric-table>
                              </p>

                              <p ng-if="section.content_type === 'aggregated-table'">
                                <aggregated-table model="section.selectedTables">
                                </aggregated-table>
                              </p>

                              <p ng-if="section.content_type === 'text-table'">
                                <free-text-table model="section.content"
                                                disable-editing="true"
                                                hide-input-controls="true">
                                </free-text-table>
                              </p>

                              <p ng-if="section.content_type === 'chart'">
                                <multi-chart model="section.content"
                                            tables="section.selectedTables"
                                >
                                </numeric-table>
                              </p>
                          </div>
                          <div class="footer col-xs-12">
                              <div class="txt col-xs-11">copyright 2016@ {{$root.selectedCompany.name}}</div>
                              <div class="pp col-xs-1 ">Page{{sectionindex}} </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
```

Comment: How is the large block of code relevant to the question? It has no ng-repeat, and no $index. Clarify your question, post the relevant code, explain precisely the output that it produces, and the output that you desire.

Comment: sorry about that the copy paste problem

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-repeat="(index1 ,chapter) in plan.chapters" class="export-page" >
   <div  ng-repeat="(index2,section) in chapter.sections track by section.id" class="export-page" ng-init="sectionindex = $index">
        Outer Repeat Index{{index1}}
        Inner Repeat Index{{index2}}
   </div>
</div>
```